# UIImage: Resize, then Crop

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, core-graphics

I've been bashing my face into this one for literally days now and even though I feel constantly that I am right on the edge of revelation, I simply cannot achieve my goal.

I thought, ahead of time in the conceptual phases of my design, that it would be a trivial matter to grab a image from the iPhone's camera or library, scale it down to a specified height, using a function equivalent to the **Aspect Fill** option of UIImageView (entirely in code), and then **crop off** anything that did not fit within a passed CGRect.

Getting the original image from camera or library, was trivial. I am shocked at how difficult the other two steps have proved to be.

The attached image shows what I am trying to achieve. Would someone please be kind enough to hold my hand? Every code example I have found so far seems to smash the image, be upside down, look like crap, draw out of bounds, or otherwise just not work correctly.

Comment: The link is broken to your image.

Comment: One thing none if us is shocked about is why Apple have not added it to UIImagePickerController - its too darned difficult ;-)

Answer (score 249, accepted):

I needed the same thing - in my case, to pick the dimension that fits once scaled, and then crop each end to fit the rest to the width. (I'm working in landscape, so might not have noticed any deficiencies in portrait mode.)  Here's my code - it's part of a categeory on UIImage. Target size in my code is always set to the full screen size of the device.

```
@implementation UIImage (Extras)

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Scale and crop image

- (UIImage*)imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
    UIImage *sourceImage = self;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;    
    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;
    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) 
    {
        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor) 
        {
            scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
        }
        else
        {
            scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width
        }

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image
        if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            {
                thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
            }
        }
    }   

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); // this will crop

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");
    }

    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: curiously it works in the simulator but on the device i receive the ExecBadAccess..

Comment: Same here. Once moved to the device, I received intermittent errors. the code below, provided by Brad Lawson, works similarly, without the errors.

Comment: The problem with the bad exec is occurs, because the UIImage functions are not thread safe. Thats why it sometemes crashes, sometimes not

Comment: @Chris Beeson, if I use this method only in one thread, not in any other thread, will that be safe?

Comment: This code worked great for me, but it was blurry on retina. Combining this code with the comment below made everything perfect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop#comment11293037_604334

Comment: Use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, YES, 0.0); to make image nice on retina also.

Comment: This works for me in Portrait mode, but not landscape. The height is stretched in landscape. Any idea why?

Comment: Never mind. 2 days trying all sorts of code to get cropping working, and I didn't have auto layout set on my UIImageview displaying the final image. Thanks for this

Comment: This can only be run on the main thread. If your app uses anything but the main thread you should avoid this code in favor of something that does not use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext and UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Comment: Oh, the problem raises when I operate with portrait image. I thought, this will be ok, but it isn't.

Comment: Apple's doc says about UIGraphicsBeginImageContext "This function may be called from any thread of your app."  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

Answer (score 77):

An older post contains code for a method to resize your UIImage.  The relevant portion is as follows:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
               scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return newImage;
}
```

As far as cropping goes, I believe that if you alter the method to use a different size for the scaling than for the context, your resulting image should be clipped to the bounds of the context.

Comment: Makes NO SENSE as to why this fixes image orientation, but it does and thus it fixed my problem with the camera not returning the right orientation in the `originalImage`. Thanks.

Comment: I found that resizing an image on a retina device was appearing blurry. To maintain clarity, I modified the first line to the following: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, 1.0f, 0.0f);`. (explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display)

Comment: It rotates the image - but doesn't crop it properly! Why does it have so many votes up?

Answer (score 19):

```
+ (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)targetSize {
    //If scaleFactor is not touched, no scaling will occur      
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 1.0;

    //Deciding which factor to use to scale the image (factor = targetSize / imageSize)
    if (image.size.width > targetSize.width || image.size.height > targetSize.height)
        if (!((scaleFactor = (targetSize.width / image.size.width)) > (targetSize.height / image.size.height))) //scale to fit width, or
            scaleFactor = targetSize.height / image.size.height; // scale to fit heigth.

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); 

    //Creating the rect where the scaled image is drawn in
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake((targetSize.width - image.size.width * scaleFactor) / 2,
                             (targetSize.height -  image.size.height * scaleFactor) / 2,
                             image.size.width * scaleFactor, image.size.height * scaleFactor);

    //Draw the image into the rect
    [image drawInRect:rect];

    //Saving the image, ending image context
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}
```

I propose this one. Isn't she a beauty? ;)

Comment: This one is good, if you remove first if statement it acts as AspectFill.

Answer (score 15):

There's a great piece of code related to the resizing of images + several other operations. I came around this one when trying to figure ou how to resize images...
http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Answer (score 10):

This is a version of Jane Sales' answer in Swift. Cheers!

```
public func resizeImage(image: UIImage, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    var returnImage: UIImage?

    var scaleFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    var scaledWidth = size.width
    var scaledHeight = size.height
    var thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)

    if !CGSizeEqualToSize(image.size, size) {
        let widthFactor = size.width / image.size.width
        let heightFactor = size.height / image.size.height

        if widthFactor > heightFactor {
            scaleFactor = widthFactor
        } else {
            scaleFactor = heightFactor
        }

        scaledWidth = image.size.width * scaleFactor
        scaledHeight = image.size.height * scaleFactor

        if widthFactor > heightFactor {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (size.height - scaledHeight) * 0.5
        } else if widthFactor < heightFactor {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (size.width - scaledWidth) * 0.5
        }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)

    var thumbnailRect = CGRectZero
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint
    thumbnailRect.size.width = scaledWidth
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight

    image.drawInRect(thumbnailRect)
    returnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return returnImage
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here you go. This one is perfect ;-)

EDIT: see below comment - "Does not work with certain images, fails with: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0 error"

```
// Resizes the image according to the given content mode, taking into account the image's orientation
- (UIImage *)resizedImageWithContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode imageToScale:(UIImage*)imageToScale bounds:(CGSize)bounds interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
    //Get the size we want to scale it to
    CGFloat horizontalRatio = bounds.width / imageToScale.size.width;
    CGFloat verticalRatio = bounds.height / imageToScale.size.height;
    CGFloat ratio;

    switch (contentMode) {
        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
            ratio = MAX(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
            break;

        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
            ratio = MIN(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Unsupported content mode: %d", contentMode];
    }

    //...and here it is
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(imageToScale.size.width * ratio, imageToScale.size.height * ratio);


    //start scaling it
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = imageToScale.CGImage;
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                newRect.size.width,
                                                newRect.size.height,
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                0,
                                                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef));

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, quality);

    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    // Clean up
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Look really beautiful :) I like InterpolationQuality here

Comment: Does not work with certain images, fails with: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0 error

Answer (score 4):

I found that the Swift 3 posted by Evgenii Kanvets does not uniformly scale the image.

Here is my Swift 4 version of the function that does not squish the image:

```
static func resizedCroppedImage(image: UIImage, newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage? {

    // This function returns a newImage, based on image
    // - image is scaled uniformaly to fit into a rect of size newSize
    // - if the newSize rect is of a different aspect ratio from the source image
    //     the new image is cropped to be in the center of the source image
    //     (the excess source image is removed)

    var ratio: CGFloat = 0
    var delta: CGFloat = 0
    var drawRect = CGRect()

    if newSize.width > newSize.height {

        ratio = newSize.width / image.size.width
        delta = (ratio * image.size.height) - newSize.height
        drawRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -delta / 2, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height + delta)

    } else {

        ratio = newSize.height / image.size.height
        delta = (ratio * image.size.width) - newSize.width
        drawRect = CGRect(x: -delta / 2, y: 0, width: newSize.width + delta, height: newSize.height)

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0.0)
    image.draw(in: drawRect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: I had to set scaling to 1.0 in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` but others worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I found a small flaw in the logic. Instead of checking `if newSize.width > newSize.height`, it needs to check `if aspectRatio < newAspectRatio`.  I posted an update to @ChrisCapener's code as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I modified Brad Larson's Code. It will aspect fill the image in given rect.

```
-(UIImage*) scaleAndCropToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    float ratio = self.size.width / self.size.height;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

    if (ratio > 1) {
        CGFloat newWidth = ratio * newSize.width;
        CGFloat newHeight = newSize.height;
        CGFloat leftMargin = (newWidth - newHeight) / 2;
        [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(-leftMargin, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    }
    else {
        CGFloat newWidth = newSize.width;
        CGFloat newHeight = newSize.height / ratio;
        CGFloat topMargin = (newHeight - newWidth) / 2;
        [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, -topMargin, newSize.width, newSize.height/ratio)];
    }

    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Tested with two other images, portrait and landscape. This is NOT performing the Aspect Fill.

Answer (score 2):

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeigth)];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];
    image=[image scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeigth)];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    UIImageView* imageViewBk = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageViewBk];
    CGRect rect;
    rect.origin.x=0;
    rect.origin.y=0;
    rect.size.width = image.size.width;
    rect.size.height = image.size.height;

    [imageView setFrame:rect];

    [scrollView setContentSize:[imageView frame].size];
    [scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:[scrollView frame].size.width / [imageView frame].size.width];
    [scrollView setZoomScale:[scrollView minimumZoomScale]];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    [[self view] addSubview:scrollView];
```

then you can take screen shots to your image by this

```
float zoomScale = 1.0 / [scrollView zoomScale];
CGRect rect;
rect.origin.x = [scrollView contentOffset].x * zoomScale;
rect.origin.y = [scrollView contentOffset].y * zoomScale;
rect.size.width = [scrollView bounds].size.width * zoomScale;
rect.size.height = [scrollView bounds].size.height * zoomScale;

CGImageRef cr = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([[imageView image] CGImage], rect);

UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cr];

CGImageRelease(cr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.iOS version for [accepted answer on how to resize and then crop UIImage (Aspect Fill)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605385/883738) is
below

```
    public static UIImage ScaleAndCropImage(UIImage sourceImage, SizeF targetSize)
    {
        var imageSize = sourceImage.Size;
        UIImage newImage = null;
        var width = imageSize.Width;
        var height = imageSize.Height;
        var targetWidth = targetSize.Width;
        var targetHeight = targetSize.Height;
        var scaleFactor = 0.0f;
        var scaledWidth = targetWidth;
        var scaledHeight = targetHeight;
        var thumbnailPoint = PointF.Empty;
        if (imageSize != targetSize)
        {
            var widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
            var heightFactor = targetHeight / height;
            if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
            {
                scaleFactor = widthFactor;// scale to fit height
            }
            else
            {
                scaleFactor = heightFactor;// scale to fit width
            }
            scaledWidth = width * scaleFactor;
            scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;
            // center the image
            if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
            {
                thumbnailPoint.Y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5f;
            }
            else
            {
                if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
                {
                    thumbnailPoint.X = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5f;
                }
            }
        }
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, false, 0.0f);
        var thumbnailRect = new RectangleF(thumbnailPoint, new SizeF(scaledWidth, scaledHeight));
        sourceImage.Draw(thumbnailRect);
        newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        if (newImage == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("could not scale image");
        }
        //pop the context to get back to the default
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        return newImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I converted [Sam Wirch's guide to swift](http://www.samwirch.com/blog/cropping-and-resizing-images-camera-ios-and-objective-c) and it worked well for me, although there's some very slight "squishing" in the final image that I couldn't resolve.

```
func resizedCroppedImage(image: UIImage, newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage {
    var ratio: CGFloat = 0
    var delta: CGFloat = 0
    var offset = CGPointZero
    if image.size.width > image.size.height {
        ratio = newSize.width / image.size.width
        delta = (ratio * image.size.width) - (ratio * image.size.height)
        offset = CGPointMake(delta / 2, 0)
    } else {
        ratio = newSize.width / image.size.height
        delta = (ratio * image.size.height) - (ratio * image.size.width)
        offset = CGPointMake(0, delta / 2)
    }
    let clipRect = CGRectMake(-offset.x, -offset.y, (ratio * image.size.width) + delta, (ratio * image.size.height) + delta)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0.0)
    UIRectClip(clipRect)
    image.drawInRect(clipRect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

If anyone wants the objective c version, it's on his website.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Swift 3 version of [Sam Wirch's guide to swift](http://www.samwirch.com/blog/cropping-and-resizing-images-camera-ios-and-objective-c/) posted by William T.

```
extension UIImage {

    static func resizedCroppedImage(image: UIImage, newSize:CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        var ratio: CGFloat = 0
        var delta: CGFloat = 0
        var offset = CGPoint.zero

        if image.size.width > image.size.height {
            ratio = newSize.width / image.size.width
            delta = (ratio * image.size.width) - (ratio * image.size.height)
            offset = CGPoint(x: delta / 2, y: 0)
        } else {
            ratio = newSize.width / image.size.height
            delta = (ratio * image.size.height) - (ratio * image.size.width)
            offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: delta / 2)
        }

        let clipRect = CGRect(x: -offset.x, y: -offset.y, width: (ratio * image.size.width) + delta, height: (ratio * image.size.height) + delta)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0.0)
        UIRectClip(clipRect)
        image.draw(in: clipRect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ChrisCapener's Swift version has a small bug.  If the original image and the resized image are both landscape, and the original image has a higher aspect ratio than the resized image (or both portrait with original image having lower aspect ratio), the wrong code-path is taken.

Instead of checking `if newSize.width > newSize.height`, it needs to check `if aspectRatio < newAspectRatio`.  I made this change and moved the code into an extension on UIImage.  I also switched to using the newer UIGraphicsImageRenderer, for iOS 10+.

```
extension UIImage {
    // This function returns a newImage, based on image
    // - image is scaled uniformly to fit into a rect of size newSize
    // - if the newSize rect is of a different aspect ratio from the source
    //   image the new image is cropped to be in the center of the source image
    //   (the excess source image is removed)
    func resizedAndCroppedTo(_ newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {

        let aspectRatio = size.width / size.height
        let newAspectRatio = newSize.width / newSize.height

        var drawRect = CGRect()

        if aspectRatio < newAspectRatio {
            // width-limited
            let ratio = newSize.width / size.width
            let delta = (ratio * size.height) - newSize.height
            drawRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -delta / 2, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height + delta)
            
        } else {
            // height-limited
            let ratio = newSize.height / size.height
            let delta = (ratio * size.width) - newSize.width
            drawRect = CGRect(x: -delta / 2, y: 0, width: newSize.width + delta, height: newSize.height)
        }
        
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize).image { _ in
            draw(in: drawRect)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the results, before and after the change.  The top image has an aspect ratio of 3.33.  The middle image was resized using the original code.  It has an aspect ratio of 1.67.  As you can see, it keeps the entire image, leaving black bars on top and bottom.  The bottom image was resized using the modified code.  It correctly fills the whole view, cropping off the sides.

[image: example with original and modified code]

Comment: The first solution that worked for me from answers across various sites. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following simple code worked for me.

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: Your code does work well for `UIImageView` objects.  However, this question is about scaling the `UIImage` object itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage*)imageScale:(CGFloat)scaleFactor cropForSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
    targetSize = !targetSize.width?self.size:targetSize;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); // this will crop

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;

    thumbnailRect.size.width  = targetSize.width*scaleFactor;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = targetSize.height*scaleFactor;
    CGFloat xOffset = (targetSize.width- thumbnailRect.size.width)/2;
    CGFloat yOffset = (targetSize.height- thumbnailRect.size.height)/2;
    thumbnailRect.origin = CGPointMake(xOffset,yOffset);

    [self drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    UIImage *newImage  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");
    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Below the example of work:
    Left image - (origin image)
    ; Right image with scale x2

[image]

If you want to scale image but retain its frame(proportions), call method this way:

```
[yourImage imageScale:2.0f cropForSize:CGSizeZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
    static func imageWithImage(image:UIImage, newSize:CGSize) ->UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage
}
```

Comment: Nice little function but I'm pretty sure this just stretches the image to a particular size, doesn't keep the aspect ratio and crop...

Comment: Yes you have right, this is only for sretches the image to a paritcular size.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to have been put to rest, but in my quest for a solution that I could more easily understand (and written in Swift), I arrived at this (also posted to: [How to crop the UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635371/how-to-crop-the-uiimage/30497518#30497518))

---

I wanted to be able to crop from a region based on an aspect ratio, and scale to a size based on a outer bounding extent.  Here is my variation:

```
import AVFoundation
import ImageIO

class Image {

    class func crop(image:UIImage, crop source:CGRect, aspect:CGSize, outputExtent:CGSize) -> UIImage {

        let sourceRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(aspect, source)
        let targetRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(aspect, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: outputExtent))

        let opaque = true, deviceScale:CGFloat = 0.0 // use scale of device's main screen
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetRect.size, opaque, deviceScale)

        let scale = max(
            targetRect.size.width / sourceRect.size.width,
            targetRect.size.height / sourceRect.size.height)

        let drawRect = CGRect(origin: -sourceRect.origin * scale, size: image.size * scale)
        image.drawInRect(drawRect)

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return scaledImage
    }
}
```

There are a couple things that I found confusing, the separate concerns of cropping and resizing.  Cropping is handled with the origin of the rect that you pass to drawInRect, and scaling is handled by the size portion.  In my case, I needed to relate the size of the cropping rect on the source, to my output rect of the same aspect ratio.  The scale factor is then output / input, and this needs to be applied to the drawRect (passed to drawInRect).

One caveat is that this approach effectively assumes that the image you are drawing is larger than the image context.  I have not tested this, but I think you can use this code to handle cropping / zooming, but explicitly defining the scale parameter to be the aforementioned scale parameter.  By default, UIKit applies a multiplier based on the screen resolution.

Finally, it should be noted that this UIKit approach is higher level than CoreGraphics / Quartz and Core Image approaches, and seems to handle image orientation issues.  It is also worth mentioning that it is pretty fast, second to ImageIO, according to this post here: http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/