# to reduce image height and width while getting through URL?

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone SDK.i am getting image like

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/1.jpg"]]];
```

but how can i reduce height and width without using UIImageview?

Answer (score 0):

You mean without having to use a user visible component, ie using code only? Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more) entry which talks a lot about resizing UIImages.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk) is very close to yours and either [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk/613380#613380) or [lostInTransit's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk/613576#613576) there should do what you want.