# How to change the size of the image taken in camera

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to use photos from photo library in my game. How to make the file to be of size 280x280.
Is it possible to take the picture (captured by the camera immediately without saving) and then modify the picture and want to save

Answer (score 1):

After you get a `UIImage` from the camera, use the [method in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk) to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it's possible to edit photograph files inside the camera.

I think it's better to edit photograph files using software designed to crop and or reduce the photograph to 280 pixels.  You do want to maintain the width - height ratio when you reduce a photograph file.