# Reduce resolution of iphone camera pictures?

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, resolution, photo

I'm building an app that can upload users' photos to a webservice, and with very high resolution images, this can be both very slow and data intensive.  I was wondering if there was a way to reduce the camera resolution for my app, or reduce the resolution of the images I get back from the UIImagePickerController.  I have compressed the images as much as I can before submitting them, but this is still very slow, especially on 3G connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post: [What's the easiest way to resize/optimize an image size with the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk)

You'll need to resize the image yourself before you upload the image if you want to speed up the upload process.

Comment: Thanks, maybe sometime in the future Apple will get the hint, and let developers set or at least select a maximum resolution for the camera for applications like this or image processing

Comment: not the way to really lower the resolution to overcome memory warnings

Comment: @OMGPOP; I'd be interested to hear your solution, if you have a better one.  Cheers.

Comment: @JamieChapman nope, i encountered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490157/cocos2d-uiimagepickercontroller-memory-warning