# How to reduce size of image display on UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, image-manipulation

My problem is that, in my app I have `UIImageview`, `button1`, `button2`. `button1` is used to access images from saved photolibrary and button2 is used to store image in database,

But image size is (800x800) which is very large, I want to store it at (50x50) size

How to reduce size of image when button2 is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

```
// grab the original image
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];

UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage] scale:50/800 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Answer (score 2):

This category will do the job for you -

UIImage+Additions.h -

```
@interface UIImage (UIImageAdditions)
- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size;
@end
```

UIImage+Additions.m -

```
@implementation UIImage (UIImageAdditions)

- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height), self.CGImage);

    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image 
               scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   return newImage;
}
```

Pls see this previous SO question [What's the easiest way to resize/optimize an image size with the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk) for further reference