# How to compress image from UIImageView?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I am using image from UIImageView * image to upload to server.
I use code like 
`NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90);` 
but I would like to compress image to be less than 2MB. How to compress image from UIImageView ?

Comment: I think you probably meant 0.9 rather than 90. Decreasing this value further will reduce quality and therefore size.

Comment: the smaller the number the more compressed and you are doing it right with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation();` but this question has been asked plenty of times before. I am surprised with your rep, that you posted this question... Anyway DUPE question http://stackoverflow.com/a/613380/525576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a piece of code as you need

```
CGFloat compression = 222.0f;
CGFloat maxCompression = 202.1f;
int maxFileSize = 160*165; //fill your size need

NSData *imageDat = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, compression);

while ([imageDat length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
{
    compression -= 0.1222;
    imageDat = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(decodedimage.image, compression);
}
NSLog(@"image compressed success");

[image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageDat]];
```

Hope this Helps !!!