# Is there a way of reducing iPad photo quality

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have an app that takes a photo with the ipad camera and saves it in a sql database.

Is there away i can take a low resolution picture or a way i can reduce the picture resolution before i save it to the database.

thanks

Comment: Just pick a maximum dimension (say, 1024px) and resize the image (http://stackoverflow.com/a/613380/155187) before saving it.

Comment: Incidentally, when you say, SQL database, do you mean a local SQLite database (which can be done, but it is poorly suited for storing images other than thumbnails) or uploading to some other SQL DBMS (which is fine)?

Comment: hi there i will give them a try, currently sql locally but next phase will be server basing the database. Not best way but what i been instructed by bosses to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to reduce the quality. JPEGs are also much smaller than PNGs, if that's what you're currently saving them as.

```
NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .8);
```