# How to resize image when fetch from URL in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, crash, uiimageview

I have app Containing Images Which has to show in cells of `UITableView` 
 

for this images `URL` coming from server. This images are HD or some time it is normal images. 
 I am using `SDImageCashe` for loading image from server and to show.

Some Times this will `crash` my app due to loading this images.

Can any one tell me how to resize this images so that to avoid `memory issues`.

Also one thing this image i have to show in TableView, and this contain is pagination.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Y**ou should do this on serverside.while creating the api,the web developer can upload a hd image and the server automatically creates hd,sd,low and thumbnails for the image.google it and you will get it.I am an ios developer and i dont know much about it in the server side.

Comment: Yes, this is one way. but I want to know is there any thing which can be sone our side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk may be this will help.But its always better to do it on server side

Answer (score 0):

Orthogonal to your issue, but you should consider resizing your image server-side (to save bandwidth/make things faster). Thumbor is one such library which you can leverage.