# How to edit high resolution images with Core Graphics?

Tags: swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a path on a high resolution image, that's nothing complicated for an iPhone but if I add shadow to my path everything lags. It lags only when I work on images with a certain resolution (2000 x 3000) even less.
The **Storyboard** vies are:

```
-Scroll View
  -Image View
  -Draw View
```

So I have the DrawingView on top of the ImageView when I need to draw.
So the ImageView and the DrawView (`view.bounds.size`) have the same resolution as the image (e.g. 2000 x 3000) (**there's the problem**). 
I'm drawing on a view with a high resolution.

I'm **not directly calling `drawRect:`** but only calling `setNeedsDisplay()` inside `touchesBegan()` and `touchesMoved()` after doing some operations (`path.moveToPoint`, `path.addCurveToPoint`, array operations)  and adding points to my array.

In `drawRect:` I essentially have:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        print(self.bounds.size)
        UIColor.greenColor().setStroke()
        path.lineCapStyle = .Round
        path.lineJoinStyle = .Round
        path.lineWidth = 60.0
        context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath)
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeZero, 14.0, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)  // <-- with this shadow it lags a lot.
        path.stroke()
    }
```

My path is a `UIBezierPath()`.

Any ideas to improve the speed?

**Update:**
I followed what @brimstone said. I now have ImageView with a lower resolution, but have to apply my drawn path to the high resolution image. 
(I'm trying to hand crop an image with the path that the user draws)
In this code I already got my closed path:

```
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = path.CGPath
    self.imageToEditView.layer.mask = layer
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageEdited.size)
    self.imageToEditView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let croppedCGImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage!, CGPathGetBoundingBox(path.CGPath))
    let croppedImage = UIImage(CGImage: croppedCGImage!)
    self.imageToEditView.image = croppedImage
    self.imageToEditView.layer.mask = nil
```

`imageToEditView.bounds.size` = low resolution
`imageEdited.size` = high resolution

I need to set the hight resolution (I think) when i `renderInContext`. But how can I change the resolution of the imageView now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downsizing it for the user to draw over (doesn't make a huge difference on small iPhone screens for user experience), then apply the edits to the high-res image.

To downsize images, either use `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, which may make your image sufficiently smaller, or (if you're still having memory issues), try using techniques in [this tutorial](http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk) to make it even smaller.

Then, you can take the content of what they've drawn and apply it to the high-res image.

Alternatively, look at high-res optimisation techniques by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll check it Friday. Will I be able to apply the content of my drawn from the small resolution to the higher one?

Comment: If your drawView is separate from your image view, you can have the user draw whatever, then apply what they've drawn to the high-res image. It doesn't matter about the low-res image if it's just in the background of them drawing.

Comment: I'm having some problems to apply the path to the high resolution image. I updated the answer