# Converting UILabel into UIImage giving wrong size and poor quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uilabel, uigraphicscontext

I have a `UILabel` of size `180 x 180` and I am converting it in the `image`, but when I am saving it I am getting `540 x 540` image resolution, I need `180 x 180`. Here is my code.

```
- (void)grabImage {
    // Create a "canvas" (image context) to draw in.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_lbl1.bounds.size, _lbl1.opaque, 0.0);  // high res
    // Make the CALayer to draw in our "canvas".
    [[_lbl1 layer] renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    // Fetch an UIImage of our "canvas".
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Stop the "canvas" from accepting any input.
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image180.png"]; //Add the file name
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file

}
```

---

The quality is poor, in attached image upper one is original `UILable` and at bottom is the generated image, see the difference

[image]

Comment: THis is because  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_lbl1.bounds.size, _lbl1.opaque, 0.0);. You should pass the screen scale and not 0.0. Reason for 540 size is 180 x 3 (which is the scale of the device you're on)

Comment: Please can you give the code snippet how to do that ......

Comment: I passed the [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] in place of 0.0 but still same

Comment: @GeneCode I passed 1.0 but image quality in poor..... what should I do to keep image quality high and resolution 180 x 180

Comment: You should use mainScreen scale. Then just resize it manually i guess. Use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: @GeneCode I have attached the image see the image quality, no method is working

Comment: please [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4334902/3308174)