# How do I resize and save an image on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to save the image that is pinched to different size from original size. How could 
I save it? How should I write the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find your answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more

Comment: Thank you for the link you have given.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to these questions provide a few different ways of resizing UIImages:

- ["What’s the easiest way to resize/optimize an image size with the iPhone SDK?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk)
- ["UIImage: Resize, then Crop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop)