# Custom image mask in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, calayer, puzzle, cashapelayer

I have a issue with masking images. I do game "puzzle" and have to make custom images. I found and tried 2 way of custom cropping:

1. Using `CALayer.mask` property.
2. Using `UIImage.mask` property.

In first option i create my custom path, then assign it to `CAShapeLayer.path` property, then assign `CAShapeLayer` to `CALayer.mask` property. At the end i have custom cropped image. 
In second option i use firstly use `CGImageMaskCreate()` method (i use previously created black mask images of puzzle), then `CGContextClipToMask()`. 
In either options i have problem with performance (mostly when i crop image into 16 puzzles and drag in over the screen).

Is there any **other approaches** to crop image in custom way. 
(I don't know how to solve performance problem).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are asking about is NOT cropping, it's called masking. You have repeatedly stated that you want to mask non-rectangular regions; cropping almost always refers to rectangular regions. You may want to adjust the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of UIImage-categories out there you can use for this. Give me a moment and I'll post some links here:

- [Cropping an UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage) (not really a category though, but it'll fit)
- [UIImage: Resize, then Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop)
- https://sites.google.com/a/injoit.com/knowledge-base/for-developers/graphics/uiimage-routines-scaling-cropping-rotating-etc
- http://www.hive05.com/2008/11/crop-an-image-using-the-iphone-sdk/
- http://maybelost.com/2010/11/cropping-a-uiimage-on-iphone/

Comment: Thanks for answer, Tim van Elsloo. But this links consists manuals about cropping a rectangle image. But i need a custom. Not rectangle. Like this one: http://imageshack.us/f/856/hard131.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);

    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return cropped;
}

...

UIImage *temp_image = [self imageByCropping:original_image toRect:clipping_rectangle];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Martin. But your source code can only cropping rectangle regions. But i not need it. I need to crop rectangle image into this one: http://imageshack.us/f/856/hard131.png.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider about drawing the image in a new image with an alpha background an overdrawing the current background. I mean: All pixel which are inside the jigsaw piece: normal colour, all pixels outside the jigsaw piece = transparent. And then try to blend it to the new background or overdrawing it.

Just my 2 cents. :)