# ImagePicker Library with custom crop rect?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have been searching around for a long time now trying to find a custom UIImagePickerController-like library that enables custom crop sizes.  I've also read a number of posts on this site and others:

- [Custom image crop in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880597/custom-image-crop-in-ios)
- [UIImage: Resize then crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop)
- [Cropping a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage)
- [Custom crop rect for UIImagePickerController](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40124-custom-crop-rect-uiimagepickercontroller.html)

As you'll notice most of the questions address how to effectively crop an image once you have the resource, but most don't address a custom crop rect.  There are plenty of other answers that all point to Apple's documentation which states that you can't modify their UIImagePickerController to have custom crop size.  That's great to know, however I find it absurd that there isn't a library on the web that enables custom crop rects.  Is there really no resource anywhere?!?!?

I would pay money to have a good library for this.  Does anybody know of one?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [GKImagePicker](https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker)

The sample project only has iphone and only supports photo album, but I was fairly easily able to extend it to include ipad and camera. I have used it to make a custom crop view that it a rounded rectangle. If i get around to it I'll turn my work into a framework.

Answer (score 2):

I tried GKImagePicker and found it to be buggy, and it hasn't received an update in quite a while. Switched to [ios-image-editor](https://github.com/heitorfr/ios-image-editor) for much better results.

Comment: buggy as hell and deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not built to be used as a library, if you're out of options you may want to dive in to the code in [this](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/CropImageSample) github repository.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this link there is a book (I bought it) that shows you how to implement "taking a picture" and "picking a picture from the library". Both ways, after the picture is token/chosen the user is allowed to crop the image and then you can do whatever you want with the cropped picture.

[Beginning iPhone 4 Development](http://www.apress.com/9781430230243)