# iOS - Image crop with gesture in circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, crop

I am developing an iOS app in which I need to crop image with finger. Like any one take picture and then can crop any part of image with finger. I have searched the Internet but I am getting tools what can crop images into rectangular area. Can anyone please help me to crop image with pan gesture with rough pattern?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I did this by drawing bezierpath to image and then got masked image.

Comment: Thank you joseph for editing

Answer (score 1):

There is not straight API from apple to help you do that. You will have to create your own custom mask layer and get the image.graphic context and apply the user created mask to that context your self.

You might want to dig deeper into this thread: [ImagePicker Library with custom crop rect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217842/imagepicker-library-with-custom-crop-rect)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this one solution](https://github.com/nicholjs/BFCropInterface) which mentioned all requirement.