# How to crop Image using rectangle?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

[image: Rectangle used to crop]

I am trying to crop an image using this rectangle.But Not getting how to stretch the rectangle.I am having one `UIView` that is outside and within that other view shown with `black border`. When I stretch DO i need to change the frame for both `UIView`s ??

should use `Pinchgesture` to stretch the rectangle or any other method??

Here four blue handlers are `UIView` s. How will i determine the dragging of them??
If there please suggest.

Comment: I have not done like this but here is some link which may be useful to you. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880597/custom-image-mask-in-ios, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087435/image-cropping-api-for-ios, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage

Comment: Check this link it contains which you you want : https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper

Comment: @Devang I have already created rectangle for that.Just need to drag that and set

Comment: BJImageCropper will give you some idea. It contains that drag feature.

Comment: you jush need to assign a cropView and add gesture to it to resize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code for the selecting the box and cropping the image.

```
-(IBAction) cropImage:(id) sender{
    // Create rectangle that represents a cropped image  
    // from the middle of the existing image
float xCo,yCo;
float width=bottomCornerPoint.x-topCornerPoint.x;
float height=bottomCornerPoint.y-topCornerPoint.y;
if(width<0)
width=-width;
if(height<0)
    height=-height;
         if(topCornerPoint.x <bottomCornerPoint.x)
         {
               xCo=topCornerPoint.x;
          }
         else 
         {
             xCo=bottomCornerPoint.x;
         } 
        if(topCornerPoint.y <bottomCornerPoint.y)
        {
             yCo=topCornerPoint.y;
         }
      else {
             yCo=bottomCornerPoint.y;
       }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xCo,yCo,width,height);
    // Create bitmap image from original image data,
    // using rectangle to specify desired crop area
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    // Create and show the new image from bitmap data
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 600, width, height)];
    imageView.image=img;
    [[self view] addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
```

Hope this may helping to lot