# how to display big image in a small rect in ipad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I'm doing my very first application for iPad. My problem is I'm having 1024*768 image. i want to keep that image in 100*100 imageview. But I'm getting the full size of the image .please any one help me.

Thank You
Praveena

Comment: Just show us some code as to what you've right now and we will help you from there.

Comment: You need to clarify your question by saying, for example, whether you want to crop the 'big image' or show it as a thumbnail.

Comment: I'm a sorry to ask this type of silly question. I got it. I'm a big stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the following thread
[UIImage: Resize, then Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop)