# Provide UIImagePicker with your own UIImage.

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, customization

I'm trying to get a downloaded photo that was saved on the device (not photo library), and put that UIImage in a UIImagePickerController so i can crop it (using allowsEditing), as when i would choose it from my own Photo Library.

Does anyone know if this is possible in any way but building my own crop-screen ? (would really rather not do it.)

Thanks in advance,
Shai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way you can assign an image to *UIImagePickerController* and make directly open the ***Move and Scale*** view.

You have to create your own view controller that acts like *Move and Scale* and do your cropping there.

Comment: Thats unfortunate to hear :( I hope anyone else would have a more optimistic answer. thank you anyways for the reply.

Comment: check this link if it helps...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop