# Where is the small, medium, large, original image functionality from Apple's Mail app?

Tags: iphone, ios

When sharing an image in an iPhone, we are given an opportunity to pick different sizes of an image - Small, Medium, Large, Original. And an opportunity of see the size in KB/MB along with each classification.

1. Where does apple expose this code for users to leverage? I couldn't spot it in my searches in iOS docs.
2. What are some tested & tried frameworks/methods available on GitHub or elsewhere that can emulate this behavior?

EDITED:
I evaluated the solution posted by Brad Larson:
[UIImage: Resize, then Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop)
By confirming a decrease in size via the size measuring solution given below.
Together they are a good fit.

Comment: @Kashiv please don't change the intended title of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking specifically about compression

Comment: 2012-02-22 00:24:24.130  took a picture..................
2012-02-22 00:24:24.136  Original 2592x1936 (19.14 MB)...
2012-02-22 00:24:24.300  Original 100x100 (0.04 MB)......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Where does apple expose this code for users to leverage? I couldn't spot it in my searches in iOS docs.

iOS is not open-source project. Apple releases only sample code which is used like tutorial sample project.

---

[Here's an article](http://hsc.csu.edu.au/ipt/mm_systems/3289/image_file_size.htm) regarding calcutation of image file size.

This is very simple, though. Here's the code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_big_image.png"];

size_t depth = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(image.CGImage);
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);

double bytes = ((double)width * (double)height * (double)depth) / 8.0;
```

Now you have your image size in **bytes**.

To convert it to kB divide it by 1024. If you want to get MB, divide by 1048576 *(1024x1024)*.

```
double kb = bytes / 1024.0f;
double mb = bytes / 1048576.0f
```

Then you can display it to your user by formatting your message as following:

```
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Original %dx%d (%.2f MB)", (int)width,(int)height, (float)mb];
```

Comment: You mean how to compress image or how to read if it's compressed?

Comment: I mean, how to calculate the target size of the compressed image, without scaling and compressing it first.

Comment: The image size was an example, my actual question is: Do you know if Apple happens to expose their implementation for compressing images or not? :)

Comment: @pulkitsinghal And the answer is no.

Comment: Works well when combined with and used to validate Brad Larson's solution for compression & scaling provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop