# crop an image in iPhone by selecting an area

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In My iPhone application,I  want to crop an image.That means i want to select the area that i want from the image and need to crop it.The area of selection can be rectangle,circle..like that.Can anyone help me by giving some code?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you're looking to outsource your development, then you've chosen the wrong site.  This is for code and programming related questions.  Show your code and we can help you with it.

Comment: You can look at this post. It has all codes you need.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find [IGFramework](http://code.google.com/p/igframework-iphone-static-library-project/source/checkout) useful. It comes in a form of static library and
also holds a method for cropping images. As for circle cropping you'll probably
have to crop a rectangle and mask with a circle.

Nice tutorial of masking an image is here: [How to Mask an Image](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html)

Answer (score 0):

A component is available from Cocoa Controls :
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/imagecropper

Comment: I have already tried these all..But I want something like for example we have a photo in our device.and we want that photo to use for some purpose.so, I want to delete the unnecessary part from it.that i could not mention earlier.

Comment: Code: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4063768?start=0&tstart=0