# Crop UIImage to fit a frame image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage

I need to crop a `UIImage`, taken with the device camera, so that it fits inside another `UIImage`, which represents a `frame` (with rounded borders and so on). Check the image below:

[image]
Using Aspect Fill

[image]
Using Aspect Fit

So, what I need is to remove the image excess that is out of the frame bounds.
I tried using `UIBezierPath`, `CGImageRef` and other methods that I Googled but I'm not finding a solution for this.

Comment: are you creating the frame programmatically or inside IB?

Comment: The UIImageViews are within a xib file

Comment: I got it using this [answer][1]! 
Thanks for your attention to help me!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop

Comment: Have you tried `clipsToBounds`?

Comment: @CainaSouza you should accept the answer you deem to be correct

Answer (score 128):

In Interface Builder, use the following configuration:

[image]

There are two important settings, namely:

1. `Mode: Aspect Fill`
2. `Clip Subviews`

It can also be done programmatically:

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

This will correctly fill the view with the image, keep its aspect ratio and hide what doesn't fit.

Comment: If you need to do this programmatically then use `[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];`  
`[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];`

Comment: I've been using AVCapture to take photo's and always ended up with a stretch on the UIImageView - after seeing these 2 lines of code.. it's brought my many hours of searching to an end! Thank you so much! I got everything right apart from ClipsToBounds.. why didn't I think of this.. it's so obvious haha! Thanks again dude!

Comment: Clip Subviews has been renamed **Clip to Bounds**

Answer (score 4):

make a `IBOutlet` in your controller.

```
@property (retain)IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;
```

and in `-(void) viewDidLoad` set

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: There is a small typo on the property name.  It should be: 
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 1):

In interface Builder, access the *Mode* menu inside of the detail pane (the fourth one) and choose the right one for your `UIImageView` (I guess "center" or "aspect fit").

[image]

OLD ANSWER:

You can use the [`contentGravity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/contentsGravity) property of CALayer to make it work

> A constant that specifies how the layer's contents are positioned or scaled within its bounds.
>
> ```
>        @property(copy) NSString *contentsGravity
> ```

Comment: Didn't work using "Center"... The image fit all the view, beyond the frame image. Do you have an example of how to use the contentsGravity?

Comment: This keeps the image aspect but I get some blank areas in the top and bottom of the frame image.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I posted this, it was with aspect fill. Is there any parameter I need to set in IB, beyond Aspect Fill?

Comment: maybe you could post some pictures of the results you are getting... it is difficult to follow...

Comment: I got it using the answer posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Use an `UIImageView` and do

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: This keeps the image aspect but I get some blank areas in the top and bottom of the frame image.