# iOS estimatedRowHeight not working in plus device

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview with setting:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;
```

It's work fine in 5/5s, 6/6s, 7 but its not working in 6s+/7+, images is stretch.

[image: 5/5s 6/6s, 7 devices] 
[image: 6s+/7+ devices]

Comment: I think, you should set contentMode and layoutConstraints for UIImageView

Comment: layoutConstraints is always, contentMode not working, row height is very small in plus devices

Comment: Can you give more information regarding layout constraints of this cell and imageView?

Comment: Change contentmode of UIImageView as AspectFill and clips to bound true. Hope it helps!!

Comment: I can't say for sure. you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062905/uiimageview-with-aspect-fill-inside-custom-uitableviewcell-using-autolayout

Comment: layout constraint match with 4 edges and  UIImageView as AspectFill and clips to bound true not working

Comment: are there two images exist in single cell ?

Comment: I am use 1 image with size 2x1 (200x100)

Comment: Another devices is ok, but 6+/6s+/7+ not working :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make content mode of Uiimageview to Aspect fill .It will solve your issue

Comment: Cell height in plus devices is small than normal devices :( so, cell is stretch

Comment: have you used aspect ratio? if not then please use it in your contraints.

Comment: No, my cell with single image constraint 4 edges, no more. Setup table with estimatedRowHeight + rowHeight. My 6s work fine :( 6s+ is fail

Comment: add aspect ration as well. It will solve you issue as aspect ratio is used for the image to look proper in all screen size.

Comment: Aspect ratio is good with fix size image. So, I want appear any images with any size ? Any suggest ? Thank @Raman

Comment: Aspect ratio is even good with dynamic size images as well. When you will use autolayout for your image don't add contraints for height and width just use aspect ratio. It will work fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147836/discussion-between-znapps-and-raman-srivastava).