# Crop a specific area of an UIImage from an UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

my heading is exploding with this issue.

I am want to implement something similar to the camera view of Instagram.
I am using an Overlay View to customise the appearance of the camera.

First issue - I couldn't make the Live View a square. Therefore, I created views to cover parts of the live view and make a square.

This solution led to my second issue. How can I crop the image that appears in the square that I made on the overlay view.

My closest solution has come from this post: [UIImage: Resize, then Crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603907/uiimage-resize-then-crop?rq=1)

Is there a way to make a square shape live preview and the use that image. Or can I make a square from a portion of the scryeen that I want without distortion or lost of quality.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) is a great framework for processing live camera feeds. It can easily implement many visual effects, including cropping.

For example, to make a square video feed from the rectangular camera input:

```
GPUImageStillCamera *camera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
camera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

// 720 / 1280 = 0.5625
GPUImageCropFilter *squareCrop = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.21875, 1.0, 0.5625)];

[camera addTarget:squareCrop];
[squareCrop addTarget:self.imageView];
[camera startCameraCapture];
```

You will need to read the GPUImage documentation to learn how to set up the framework properly, but it is quite powerful once you learn how to use it.

Comment: I tried to set it up and it didn't work. I would like to find if it is possible using camera picker though.

Comment: Well, the framework isn't broken... if you aren't going to bother spending time trying to implement a possible solution to your problem, then there's not much I can do to help you.

I recommend starting with one of the GPUImage example projects. From there it should be easy to add a crop filter to the filter chain.