# Table View UIImage rendering issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm running into a rendering issue with my tableView UIImages and was wondering if anyone has encountered the same problem and knows how to fix it.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     cell.textLabel.text = exerciseDisplayName;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

    UtilityMethods *commonMethods = [[UtilityMethods alloc]init];

    UIImage *rowImage = [commonMethods imageForRow:tempPlaceholder.bodyPart];

    cell.imageView.image = rowImage;

    return cell;

 }
```

Here is my height for row.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath                  
  {
     return 96;
  }
```

[image]

There are lots of lines and squiggles in the images in the table. I was wondering if anyone knowns any UIImage properties that I might need to apply to my image to fix the problem. Increasing the height for row in table fixes the problem at the expense of increasing the height of the table row. The number that seems to work is 128 in heightForRow. When using 128 the squiggles are much less noticeable. Now I'm pretty sure this has something to do with how iOS is rendering the image. Ive taken the image and resized it to 76x76 using Microsoft Paint just  to see if I would see the same problem, and the images appear just fine without all the squiggles. The images are .png format. The original size of the images is 1024x1024. Ive just resized them downwards as I've needed them. If anyone has any tips or advice on how to fix this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The only reason to resize an image downward is to save space.  Whatever the size of your image view is in pixels, the image your loading into it should be at least 2x that size.

Comment: I tried just leaving the image in the 1024x1024 format for the table view image. The problem is still present when the height for row is at 96. Increasing height for row back up to 128 alleviates the problem some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to resample the image to the size you need.  Viewing a large image in a small space looks rather bad on iOS devices (most any really).  But if you use built in functions to create a new UIImage of the proper size everything looks much better.  Scaling down a UIImage when displaying will always look worse than creating a new image of the proper size and displaying that.  The way to do this is as follows [(taken from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605385/1671729):

```
- (UIImage*)imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
    UIImage *sourceImage = self;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;    
    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;
    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) 
    {
        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor) 
        {
            scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
        }
        else
        {
            scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width
        }

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image
        if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            {
                thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
            }
        }
    }   

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, 0, NO); // this will crop

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");
    }

    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

That function does a bit more than you are looking for, but you should be able to cut it does to only what you need.

Make sure to use the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` function instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` so you deal with retina displays properly, otherwise this will make your images more blurry than they should be and you will have a second problem to deal with.