# How to stop UISlider to shrink the image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uislider

I am creating review (Rating Stars) display from `UISlider`, having 2 images

1. all 5 white stars and
2. all 5 red stars.

Now when i display review like this:

```
    [slider_Rating setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 25)];
    [slider_Rating setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"review.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider_Rating setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starsbackground.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider_Rating setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But the issue is `UISlider` shrink the image instead of showing it according to the value. How can i do like for example when slider has **0.5** value it should show half of the image from left side?

Sample image of my issue

[image]

## Or any other solution?

Comment: one solution is to crop images but this is not good solution

Comment: so you have to do following thing- 1. use four diff. images (red full star, red half star, white full star and white half star). and then show images or repeat images according to slider value

Comment: @LalitKumar no no i am having dynamic values from server side for rating... thats why i am using this

Comment: no problem it will work

Comment: @LalitKumar no lalit you didnt understand .. i mean the rating value could be 4.237 or 1.85 so the slider value will also change like 0.42 or 0.89

Comment: You could truncate or round the value from the slider

Comment: the thing you want to try is not gonna work in any other way

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705697/move-uiimage-inside-uiimageview

Comment: you may have to use ScrollView or use `contentMode` property