# Change the image position inside an ImageView for an animation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, imageview

Hello I am asking you if it is possible to animate the image position with UIView.animate inside an imageView, which is clip to bounds ?

Comment: Change the UIImageView frame in UIView.animate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705697/move-uiimage-inside-uiimageview

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani I don't want to animate the ImageView but the image inside.

Comment: You can make the UIView parent of UIImageView and move imageview

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Yes I thought about that. So it is impossible to move directly the image inside the imageview..

Comment: We use Image-view as wrapper to display the image if image is a view and capable to display itself so we don't need the image-view!

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani ok ty :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move UIImage inside UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705697/move-uiimage-inside-uiimageview)